# SQLite query - How to read configuration from database in just one query ? Is it possible?

Tags: c#, sqlite

can someone show me example, how I can read configuration values from database in one query ? Here is my code:

```
        public string ReadString(string Sql)
        {
            using (cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Sql, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();
                return (result == null ? "" : result.ToString());
            }            
        }
```

```
string ftpHost = DAL.ReadString("SELECT ftpHost FROM Ftp WHERE Id = '1'");
string ftpLogin = DAL.ReadString("SELECT ftpLogin FROM Ftp WHERE Id = '1'");
string ftpPassword = DAL.ReadString("SELECT ftpPassword FROM Ftp WHERE Id = '1'");
string ftpSerialPath = DAL.ReadString("SELECT ftpSerialPath FROM Ftp WHERE Id = '1'");
//Need only one query to use it in FtpClient                    
FtpClient client = new FtpClient(ftpHost, ftpLogin, ftpPassword);
```

I have try to find some examples on stackoverflow, but I can;t find it.

Comment: Dapper + model class + Query ... or learn basic of ADO.NET (IDataReader or filling DataTable)

Comment: DAL.ReadString("SELECT (ftpHost || ftpLogin || ftpPassword) FROM Ftp WHERE Id = '1'");

Comment: @Oleg You method to read data from SQL is wrong. You should use the normal way that return a typical `DataTable` object

Comment: public DataTable Select(string Sql)
        {
            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Sql, conn);
            adpt = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            adpt.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            conn.Open();
            adpt.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }

Comment: @Oleg Yes that sounds like the correct format. A `DataAdapter` is there to load up the data into a `DataSet` or `DataTable`. This actually return a table which is what you want. I will add that `DataAdapter` is actually a lot more than that but for what seems to be your level of knowledge on the subject that is enough for you to use it right now.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? An error? `ExecuteScalar` is appropriate if you want a single value from a query. Using an adapter is overkill.

Comment: @Crowcoder overkill is quite a big word. We are talking of maybe a handful of milliseconds at best here. Unless you are in a time critical application this is a non issue

Comment: @Franck who said anything about time? Adapters are made for state tracking and are very heavy in comparison. Why use them when the appropriate way is just as easy to use?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did the solution in this way with ExecuteReader

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                reader.GetValues(values);
                return string.Join(",", values);
            }
```

Comment: Well done, this is much better than multiple queries or using adapters

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you, you show me the good way to resolve this problem

Comment: One more tip. You don't need a "while" loop if you just want the first record. Just call Read() by itself

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you, will use your suggestion